# Hide mesh in some parts of Plot3D

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to hide part of the mesh in a Plot3D plot? For example, in the plot

`Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, Mesh -> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}]`

could I hide the mesh for x<2 and y<2?

My goal is to show a specific mesh in a Plot3D without modifying the internal mesh used for plotting, as this would be too expensive to get the desired mesh. The grid I want displayed is roughly structured, so I could plot it in the way above and just remove those parts of the lines I do not want.

Comment: Use a `RegionFunction` like this: `Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, Mesh -> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ! (x < 2 && y < 2)]]` or do you want to keep the surface too?

Comment: Yes I want to keep the surface, I just want to control what information I show with the mesh lines.

Comment: Just a quick hack on @flinty's answer: `Show[
 Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {All, All, {-2, 8}},
   Mesh -> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ! (x < 2 && y < 2)]],
 Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, Mesh -> None, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, (x < 2 && y < 2)]]
 ]`

Comment: @CraigCarter Better: `Show[Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> None, 
  Mesh -> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}, PlotRange -> {All, All, {-2, 8}}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ! (x < 2 && y < 2)]], 
 Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, Mesh -> None]]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use the [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) option of [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) with [`ImplictRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplictRegion.html).

With region in OP

```
r = ImplicitRegion[x < 2 && y < 2, {x, y}];
```

then

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}
 , Mesh -> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
 , MeshFunctions -> {
   If[{#1, #2} ∈ r, 0, #1] &
   , If[{#1, #2} ∈ r, 0, #2] &
   }
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use any region. However, for some you may have to increase the [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) to get the mesh to connect nicely.

For example,

```
r2 = ImplicitRegion[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 <= 1, {x, y}];

Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}
 , Mesh -> 5
 , MeshFunctions -> {
   If[{#1, #2} ∈ r2, 0, #1] &
   , If[{#1, #2} ∈ r2, 0, #2] &
   }
 , PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Easy to [`Manipluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipluate.html) as well.

```
Manipulate[
 region = 
  ImplicitRegion[(x - First@c)^2 + (y - Last@c)^2 <= 1, {x, y}];
 Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}
  , Mesh -> 5
  , MeshFunctions -> {
    If[{#1, #2} ∈ region, 0, #1] &
    , If[{#1, #2} ∈ region, 0, #2] &
    }
  , PlotPoints -> ControlActive[20, 100]
  ]
 , {{c, {2, 2}, "Center"}, {0, 0}, {4, 4}, {.01, .01}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , {region, None}
 ]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this does exactly what I want; I had a feeling this should be possible using MeshFunctions. It allows changing the mesh at no additional cost to the plot itself, except to evaluate the region.

Answer (score 7):

```
Show[
 Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
  Mesh -> None],
 Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[x + y, x >= 2 || y >= 2], 
  {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4},
  Mesh -> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: With your solution, the surface itself is generated and rendered twice. To avoid this, add `PlotStyle -> None`: `Show[Plot3D[x+y,{x,0,4},{y,0,4},Mesh->None],Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[x+y,x>=2||y>=2],{x,0,4},{y,0,4},Mesh->{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}},PlotStyle->None],PlotRange->All]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov - It is not generated twice. The first plot in only for 0 <= x <= 2 and 0 <= y <=2

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov - for a moderately "expensive" function (e.g., `f[x_, y_] := Log[PDF[BinormalDistribution[{2, 2}, {1, 1}, 0.5], {x, y}]]`, `RepeatedTiming` indicates that my suggested approach is more efficient.

Comment: Yes, but `RegionFunction` [approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261883/hide-mesh-in-some-parts-of-plot3d#comment652051_261883) still wins both in the speed and `LeafCount` of the obtained expression.